# Sync function of shove for python3 useless on read?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a simple library (module) which provides access to a global dictionary stored on the (local) filesystem via SQLite db.

Its init function looks simply like this:

```
def __init__(self,):
    import shove
    self.persistent_dict = shove.Shove('lite:///tmp/bla.sqlite')
```

The setter looks like this:

```
def store_to_cache(self,a,b):
    self.persistent_dict[a] = b
    self.persistent_dict.sync()
```

And the getter looks like this:

```
def store_to_cache(self,a):
    self.persistent_dict.sync()
    return self.persistent_dict[a]
```

Everything is nicely synchronized if I write something to the dictionary, instantiate in a second shell the class and call the getter on it. If I change the content of the dict in the first shell and instantiate the dict-class in the second shell again, everything is fine. But if I simply read from the existing instance, despite the sync, it will give me the old values.

Does the sync only works to write/push local changes, or can I make it work for re-reading? (Actually I would hope I can avoid re-reading, instead I want to synchronize - check for changes and ideally only re-read parts of it...)

Comment: Maybe use the save function instead of sync? And/or the built-in getters for Shove

Comment: There is a sync and an update function, but both do not help. There is no save function, but the writing seems to work as I do not need to do anything with the python instance that is writing to/changing the dict. What do you mean by built-in getters?

Comment: Can't find too much documentation on Shove, have you considered Shelve?